# try catch in jQuery tmpl

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

How can I write `try catch` in jQuery tmpl? I tried in two ways and get these errors:

1. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token try

```
{{each items}}  
  <div>
    <span>
    ${
        try{
            services[0].id
        }catch(e){
            throw new Error(e)
        }
    }
    </span>
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

2. Uncaught Unknown template tag: try

```
{{each items }}  
  <div>
    {{try {}}
        <span>${services[0].id}</span>
    {{} catch(e){
        throw new Error(e)
      }
    }}
  </div>
{{/each }}
```

Comment: Why use `try..catch` for this and not just `services[0] && services[0].id`?

Comment: @elclanrs Good point, but what happens if services is `undefined`? Anyway, I want to use `try catch` in another places too.